# How to use intent for sharing gallery picture to application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have added my application to the share icon on top in the gallery, but so far it only opens my application, but how do I send the picture URI and stuff to my application? I understand I have to use intent? Are there any guides around I can look at? The easy-share-action guide on google website isn't helping me much here.

Comment: Its little bit confusing question. Can you please share exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
<activity
    android:name="yourActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="test">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Handle the Incoming Content**

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// Get intent, action and MIME type
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
    } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
    }
} else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
    }
} else {
    // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
}
...
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (sharedText != null) {
    // Update UI to reflect text being shared
}
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (imageUri != null) {
    // Update UI to reflect image being shared
}
}

 void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (imageUris != null) {
    // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
 }
}
```

For more information go to [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) and [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Answer (score 0):

To handle an image in your Activity you need to check if the intent has the image.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String action = intent.getAction();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {   
    if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
        // Get resource path of the stream, which in this case will be the image
    }
}
```

Furthermore you need to add to your manifest that you want to filter on these sharing image intents.

```
<activity android:name=".Theme"
       android:label="YourImageActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```